C# Winforms Dialog Cropped When Display Resolution > 100%
I have a fixed dialog where the right half is hidden under certain circumstances, and I handle this in the _Load event:
_Mru = Crud.MruTableMethods.GetMruTables();
if (_Mru == null)
{
    this.Size = new Size(275, 261);
}
else
{
    this.Size = new Size(512, 261);
}

If the size is defined in the designer, all is fine.  However, Windows 11 users who have their "Scale and Layout" set to anything greater than 100% have that amount of the dialog cropped in their view.  If they change to 100%, it looks as expected.
Is there a way I can change my size to dynamically take into effect the scale percentage?
.NET Framework 4.8
No Autosize -- a fixed dialog
DPI Awareness...  haven't seen it before, I'll take a look

You didn't specify the .NET version you're targeting, the DpiAwareness mode and the AutoScaleMode of that dialog (meaning, a standard modal Form?) -- If there's anything that's set to auto-size, specify that, too

@Jimi - .NET Framework 4.8

For .NET Framework 4.7+ (4.7.1+), see High DPI support in Windows Forms

Don't hard-code sizes and locations.  We can't see your form design, but you'd consider setting the size based on the location of a control on the form.  Say, this.Size = new Size(btnExit.Right + 20, btnExit.Bottom + 20);
